# apache vhosts ignores rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have the following vhosts file:

```
directoryindex .index.php index.html index.php
options -indexes -multiviews +followsymlinks

<directory /Volumes/dev1/http>
    allowoverride all
</directory>

<virtualhost *:80>
            documentroot "/Volumes/dev1/http"
            rewriteengine on
            rewriterule     ^.*$            /msg.php        [l]
</virtualhost>
```

There are other virtual hosts, but the one from above is the "catch-all". The problem is that the `rewriterule` is totally ignored.

Going to `site.com` gives a 403 error and `site.com/test` just returns a 404 Not Found page instead of serving the `msg.php` file.

The server is a OS X 10.8 Server running Apache 2.2.24

Comment: Tried RewriteLog? If it's created but empty, you're really in the wrong virtual host.

Comment: yes, it's created but it remains empty. what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you are in the wrong dir.
For what reason ever Apple left the .conf files for the virtual host under this directory.
/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/sites